# Send data with pending intent and get into open activity in AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I am send the data when i fire an Pending intent. After open the activity i am getting data. But it not doing anything. i don't know what is wrong in code. Please help me.

Here is my code for send data

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    System.out.println("id len: " + appWidgetIds.length);


    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) 
    {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        System.out.println("id : " + appWidgetId);  

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Report.class);
        PendingIntent pend = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_main_1);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.repClear, pend);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Map.class);
        intent1.putExtra("widgetId", appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pend1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view= new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_main_1);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton1, pend1);
        //intent1.putExtra("string", "view.getId()");
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, Map.class);
        PendingIntent pend2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view= new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_main_1);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton2, pend2);
        //intent2.putExtra("string", "view.getId()");
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);}
```

here is my code for get data

```
protected void onPostExecute(String addressText) {
        selectedLocAddress = addressText;

        //String action = intent.getAction();
        int action = getIntent().getIntExtra("widgetId",0);
        switch (action)
        {
        case R.id.imageButton1:
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_annotation_bue)).title(addressText));
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solve this problem. this is not a best solution but may help you

here is code for send data

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    System.out.println("id len: " + appWidgetIds.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        System.out.println("id : " + appWidgetId);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Report.class);
        PendingIntent pend = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main_1);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.repClear, pend);
        // view.setViewVisibility(R.id.repClear, View.INVISIBLE);
        // view.setViewVisibility(R.id.repClear1, View.VISIBLE);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Map.class);
        intent1.putExtra("data 1", true);
        intent1.setAction("myString1"+ 1);
        PendingIntent pend1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main_1);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton1, pend1);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, Map.class);
        intent2.putExtra("data 2", true);
        intent2.setAction("myString2"+ 2);
        PendingIntent pend2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main_1);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton2, pend2);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);

        Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, Map.class);
        intent3.putExtra("data 3", true);
        intent3.setAction("myString3"+ 3);
        PendingIntent pend3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 3, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main_1);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton3, pend3);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);

        Intent intent4 = new Intent(context, Map.class);
        intent4.putExtra("data 4", true);
        intent4.setAction("myString4"+ 4);
        PendingIntent pend4 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 4, intent4, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main_1);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton4, pend4);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);

        Intent intent5 = new Intent(context, Map.class);
        intent5.putExtra("data 5", true);
        intent5.setAction("myString5"+ 5);
        PendingIntent pend5 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 5, intent5, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main_1);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton5, pend5);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);

        Intent intent6 = new Intent(context, Map.class);
        intent6.putExtra("data 6", true);
        intent6.setAction("myString6"+ 6);
        PendingIntent pend6 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 6, intent6, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main_1);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton6, pend6);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);

    }
}
```

here is code for get data

```
protected void onPostExecute(String addressText) {
        selectedLocAddress = addressText;

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
         data1 = extras.getBoolean("data 1");
         data2 = extras.getBoolean("data 2");
         data3 = extras.getBoolean("data 3");
         data4 = extras.getBoolean("data 4");
         data5 = extras.getBoolean("data 5");
         data6 = extras.getBoolean("data 6");

         System.out.println("d1 "+data1+" d2 "+data2);
        if(data1==true){

            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_annotation_bue)).title(selectedLocAddress));
        }
        else if(data2==true)
        {
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_annotation_green)).title(selectedLocAddress));
        }
        else if(data3==true)
        {
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_annotation_light)).title(selectedLocAddress));             
        }
        else if(data4==true)
        {
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_annotation_purple)).title(selectedLocAddress));
        }
        else if(data5==true)
        {
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_annotation_red)).title(selectedLocAddress));
        }
        else if(data6==true)
        {
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_annotation_yellow)).title(selectedLocAddress));
        }}
```